# Deploying Django in PAAS (Clever-Cloud) / can't find my app

Tags: django, clever-cloud

I am trying to deploy my django (5.0.3) in Clever cloud

It can't locate my app on the server, although it works fine locally

Here is my tree structure

[image]

Here is my settings.py

[image]

Here are my env variables in cleveer-cloud

[image]

Here is the error :

```
2024-03-09T14:55:49+01:00 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'photos'
```

What could be the root cause ?

Comment: Can you check if django and python version same as your local environment?

Comment: Can you show tree structure of photo folder?

Answer (score 0):

You've to put this in **CC_PYTHON_MODULE**

```py
photoshare.wsgi:application
```

instead of

```py
photoshare.photoshare.wsgi:application
```

outer folder **photoshare** does not contain `__init__.py` so it's not treated as package.

### Note

Please do not post code or errors as images

Read this **[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:%7E:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.)**